# Saving image with backgroundimage to file in C#

Tags: c#, image, transparency, background-image, picturebox

I have a picturebox on the form, with BackgroundImage property set to certain image. The rest of the image has certain transparent areas, so that background image is shown in those areas. I want to save it to the file, but there is no save method for picturebox. There is a save method for image property, but then it only saves the content of the image, and does not include the backgroundimage. Any hints on how I can save both, so that it looks in the file exactly as it looks on the picturebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to accomplish this by simply combining two images together using graphics, and then saving the result as a single image object. Thus, I am not using background image anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
    bmp.Save(@"BlaBlaBlaBla.Bla");
```

edit:

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
```

Then use the drawImage method of Graphics to draw background and foreground and save the bitmap.

Comment: I didn't understand, where does this method save the image? How do I save it to file?

Comment: It didn't work. The file is created, but there is no image on it. Can it be because of transparent color use?

Comment: I don't know, I'm guessing :).

Comment: Maybe there is some other way to do what I want? My eventual goal is to create 2-layer picture, with one layer having some objects and rest filled with white color, which is set to be transparent, and the second layer is to become background for these objects. And I need to save this combination as a single image to a file.

Comment: If that's what you want, I'll add one last suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I don't know how to draw it, since background is a photograph, and objects are portraits of people.

Answer (score 0):

`g.DrawLine(myPen, EX, EY, e.X, e.Y);
               EX = e.X;`
               EY = e.Y;
               `DrawArea = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
               pictureBox1.Image = DrawArea;`

```
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"D:\C#Test_Save_File\Arash_Bashiri.bmp",    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);    `
```

Comment: Hello
maybe it is too late for your question but i have this Problem and could 
solve >it.
we have 2 layer Image but by saving ,just on of them can save!!!!

Befor saving you can combine both ,and this is possible with loading visual 
Situation befor saving .