# Saving picturebox WITH backgroundimage to file

Tags: c#, picturebox

is there any way to save a picturebox (Windows Forms) with it Backgroundimage to a file?
I tried to store the picturebox.Image into a bitmap
but its only the image itself, not the backgroundimage too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving image with backgroundimage to file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633103/saving-image-with-backgroundimage-to-file-in-c-sharp) See the accepted answer.

Comment: Save the background image to bitmap first, then draw the other image on top of it

Comment: Or you could use DrawToBitmap, which will also save any graphics you draw in the Paint event..

Comment: @TaW but DrawToBitmap isnt transparent, right? I want to save it as a PNG.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Not sure atm. If you create a transparent bitmap it should faithfully recreate the pbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two images using graphics or bitmap. There is a good example provided [here](https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/overlaying-images.htm)

Bitmap

```
 using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"Images\in.jpg"))
    using (var watermark = new Bitmap(@"Images\watermark.png"))
    {
        //Make the watermark semitransparent.
        watermark.Channels.ScaleAlpha(0.8F);
    
        //Watermark image
        bitmap.Draw(watermark, 10, bitmap.Height - watermark.Height - 40, CombineMode.Alpha);
    
        //Save the resulting image
        bitmap.Save(@"Images\Output\out.jpg");
}
```

Graphics:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"Images\in.jpg"))
    using (var watermark = new Bitmap(@"Images\watermark.png"))
    {
        //Make the watermark semitransparent.
        watermark.Channels.ScaleAlpha(0.8F);
    
        //Watermark an image.
        using (var graphics = bitmap.GetGraphics())
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(watermark, 10, bitmap.Height - watermark.Height - 40, CombineMode.Alpha);
            //Save the resulting image
            bitmap.Save(@"Images\Output\out.jpg");
        }
    }
```